# awk script inside jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am trying to execute below script inside jenkinsfile

```
awk 'NR==FNR{new=new $0 ORS; next} /^}]$/{printf "}],\n%s", new} 1' output2 ${WORKSPACE}/${REPO}/file1 >> output2
```

This script works fine in linux command promt but it gives error when tried to run inside jenkins file.I tried below

```
sh """
   awk 'NR==FNR{new=new $0 ORS; next} /^}]$/{printf "}],\n%s", new} 1' output2 ${WORKSPACE}/${REPO}/file1 >> output2
"""
```

But it gives syntax error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to watch out for escaping single or double quotes, backslashes and dollar signs. Here I've escaped everything:

```
sh """
   awk \'NR==FNR{new=new \$0 ORS; next} /^}]\$/{printf \"}],\\n%s\", new} 1\' output2 \${WORKSPACE}/\${REPO}/file1 >> output2
"""
```

Maybe you actually don't want to escape ${WORKSPACE} or ${REPO} if those are pipeline environment variables that you want substituted by groovy as opposed to by sh. And maybe you don't need to escape the single quotes inside a triple """ multistring. But you definitely need to escape the double quotes and the backslash in `\\n`.